# Двухколонный текст

Tags: css3, html5

«Двухколонный»: используя стили, сделайте страницу, в которой текст выводится в две колонки и первая буква каждой колонки оформлена в виде буквицы. 
Я знаю как сделать на одну колонку, а вот как на две?

```css
.columns{
 column-width: 200px;
 column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 30px;
 column-rule: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.columns:first-letter {
    font-size: 2em; /* Размер буквы */
    color: red; /* Цвет буквы */
    float: left; /* Выравнивание по левому краю */
    margin: 0 4px 2px 0; /* Отступы вокруг буквы */
   }
```

```html
<div class="columns">
Стоял солнечный день. Небо голубое, птицы поют. За зелёными кустами кто-то прятался, было хорошо слышно шелест сочных зелёных листьев. Там сидел маленький крольчонок и мирно пожёвывал травку, одуванчики, клевер и листочки. Заметив меня, он заторопился и, дожевав последний лист, ринулся в сторону леса. Только и видно было, как он заскочил в дальние кусты, слышно было громкий шелест и чириканье, и как множество маленьких птичек выпорхнуло из-за кустов, и эта небольшая стайка скрылась за высокими деревьями.
</div>
```

Comment: Таким способом ни как... Надо разделить текст, на две части...

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
    }
    li {
      margin-left: 20px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    li:first-letter {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: red;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: -5px; 
    }
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In possimus, accusamus porro quo maxime quibusdam ipsum quod ullam facere tenetur.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit nulla doloribus quia numquam sed autem explicabo nisi accusantium voluptas ab.</li>
    </ul>
```